# What is the best way to distribute same tableau dashboards, lenses, dataflows etc to different users(production) and orgs?

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, dataflow

We are making development of Tableau dashboards, dataflows, recipes etc for one of our client in sandbox. Once development is finished then we will deploy them using changes sets in production.

We are using sandbox because we are using Salesforce(object) data to make datasets. And now, we are having some more clients/users showing interest in Tableau CRM. They need same dashboards and other things. So, what is the best way to make same tableau assets available to these new clients as well? Without making same development over again.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are going in the direction of software distribution.  You can use Managed Package option, which will also protect your IP (login is not exposed).  For more details, you may refer this [salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_packaging_package.htm&type=5)

Comment: We can not use managed package as tableau is analyzing data from objects records from some other managed package. And if we use managed package for tableau will it able to get data from other managed package object?

Comment: Typically, you migrate the metadata (dashboard logic, recipe /data flow with rules , lens etc) to the target org and then use the target org's data sources to bring in the data and complete the step.   Are you looking to migrate some configuration data with this?   You may want to check at executive post-install scripts, please refer this from salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script.htm

Comment: Let's say a package is installed in my client1 org. I have a object abc__CustomObject1__c in this managed package and I am making datasets, dashboard etc using this abc__CustomObject1__c in sandbox of client1. And once all my dashboards and dataset are finished, I want to use these dashboards and all again for my two other clients(Orgs who have install same managed package with abc__customObject1__c). So, what do you suggest? How to make my the tableau assets available to my two(o more) other orgs?

Comment: Package route is perfectly alright for your need.  Remember, you are only using the metadata definition (of abc_CustomObject1__c) and not the records of this object in your client org.  Packages are meant for this purpose only, just to remove repetition, yet shield your IP (if you go with managed package).   Please refer the above Salesforce link shared earlier

Comment: So, for making managed package we will have to make a dev org and install my existing managed package in that org then start making datasets and all, right? Also, we have to buy Tableau CRM Plus license for this dev org? and client org which uses this tableau package.

Comment: (a) Yes, for a short answer. (b) Yes and (c) Yes - the appropriate Tableau CRM license for your features to execute as intended.